# GUI testing tool for an C++ application

Tags: c++, user-interface, testing, gui-testing

I want to choose a GUI testing tool for automated testing which with a "record and play" functionality. Could you please suggest me a tool ?

GUI framework is developed for MeeGo platform.

*Record and play*: an external applucation will be spying on host application and it`ll generate scripts and record the mouse movements and clicks. Later the recorded scripts can be played back.

Any help or suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: You have to give more detail. At the very least what toolkit and what platform.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "record and play"?

Comment: Are you going to be developing a custom GUI Framework?

Comment: @Arafangion yes the aim is to develop a custom GUI framework

Comment: @prashanth: Then you will have to implement the functionality needed for record and play yourself.

Comment: @Arafangion Go to http://www.froglogic.com  they offer a tool called Squish 4.1 i want a similar tool like that, Squish works well for Qt application because it works on Qt library, i want a similar tool for C++ applications!

Comment: @prashanth: Yes, you can't use those tools because you've chosen to develop your own GUI Framework rather than using existing frameworks (such as Qt) and existing tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could try *white* : http://white.codeplex.com/
or *TestComplete* : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestComplete

I don't know if these tools can help you though, because I don't know MeeGo.

Comment: will TestComplete support application developed in GL studio?

Comment: I doubt it will work for an application developed in GL studio. But it is worth sending an email on their forum/mailing list. For a client-server program it becomes more complicated. You will have to use another tool in addition to the gui tester. Which one ? I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for cross-platform GUI test tool have a try at eggPlant. visit - www.testplant.com.